# Django forms: Update a user's attributes without changing username

Tags: django, forms, authentication

I'm trying to create a form that allows a user to update their username or avatar. The problem that I am running into is that if I update the profile picture without changing the username, the django form validation `if form.is_valid()` will recognize the form as invalid, since the username already exists in the database. I'm using an update view, though I'm not sure I've implemented it correctly.

When I try to update the avatar without changing the username, I get a page that says "Form is invalid" from the line: `HttpResponse("Form is invalid")`. Is there a workaround to remove the form validation? I have tried removing  `if form.is_valid():` but received the error `'User_form' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'`.

I feel like there has to be an easy way around this that I have not been able to find, as so many sites allow you to update only one attribute at a time.

**Views.py**

```
    model = User
    form = User_form
    fields = ['username', 'avatar']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'

def update_profile(request, user_id): 
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = User_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            avatar = form.cleaned_data['avatar']
            if username != user.username:
                user.username = username
            if avatar != user.avatar: 
                if avatar:
                    user.avatar = avatar
            user.save()
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Form is invalid")
```

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    followed_by = models.ManyToManyField("User", blank=True, related_name="following")
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profilepics/', verbose_name='Avatar', null=True, blank=True)

class User_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'avatar']
```

**user_update_form.html**

```
<form action="/profile/{{user.id}}/update" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing too much work yourself. Django's `ModelForm`s can not only create data, but update data as well. You pass the instance through the `instance=…` parameter:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def update_profile(request, user_id): 
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = User_form(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Form is invalid')
    else:
        form = User_form(instance=user)
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'form': form})
```

For uniqness checks, it will exclude the instance when checking if the username already exists. So one can change the username, given the new username of course does not yet exists.

Comment: Ahh that totally did the trick! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: I ran into a second problem, and that was trying to get the password field to show up as a password input. Whatever I tried there, it didn't work, so I decided to get rid of the updateview altogether and just pass this in as a modelform. Now instance=user does not solve the problem because the form will not allow me to enter a blank username. I think I need to go back to the update view, but how do I make it so that the update view displays a password input and not just a normal character input field?